# How to block parameters of function which is in prototype overrided after created another object

Tags: javascript, prototype

To avoid copies of the same function I hear that functions must define in `prototype`. And I hear that OOP inheritance is suck that is why I tried to use factory function when go deep in Javascript. But I have a problem in the following code. I defined all functions in `prototype` and create two object, `emp` and `emp2`. But after defined `emp2`, parameters of `emp` is overrided. So what is benefit of factory function and prototype?

```
const eater = (state) => ({
  eat(){
    console.log(state.name, 'is eating')
  }
})



function createEmployee(name, age){
  let Employee = Object.create
    (createEmployee.prototype)
  Employee.name = name 
  Employee.age = age 
  
  Object.assign(
    createEmployee.prototype, 
    eater(Employee)
  )
  
  createEmployee.prototype.work = function(){
    console.log(Employee.name, 'is working')
  } 
 
  
  return Employee
}

let emp = createEmployee('Muzaffer', 24)
emp.work()
emp.eat()
let emp2 = createEmployee('Cuma', 22)
emp.work()
emp.eat()
//Output 
//Muzaffer is working
//Muzaffer is eating
//Cuma is working
//Cuma is eating
```

Comment: "*I hear that OOP inheritance is suck*" - which form of inheritance do you refer to? They're all OOP. And no, they don't suck if used normally. "*that is why I tried to use factory function*" - and by that you're no longer using prototypes. I mean, your `createEmployee` factory function does use a prototype but in the wrong way (and  the `eater` factory doesn't at all). Why don't you just use simple `class` syntax and try to understand what it does below the hood?

Comment: If you want to avoid making copies of functions (and that's a big IF - it's totally fine if you prefer the approach), you must not define any functions or methods *inside* a factory function.

Comment: I dont refer inheritance, I hear that composition works all stuation but class inheritance does not. I am confused about Javascript, it is not class base. Why should I use class syntax, and why dont react use class components anymore?

Comment: And what is difference between define ```createEmployee.prototype.work``` function in createEmployee factory function and out

Comment: JavaScript's inheritance implementation might not be class-based, but that doesn't mean that class as an abstract structures aren't an important concept still. That `Employee` is definitely a class with instances. And that has nothing to do with React.

Comment: The difference is that for a prototype function to be shared, it must not be re-created with every call to the factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work when using `this` keyword without `new` keyword.

```js
"use strict";
const eater = () => ({
  eat(){
    console.log(this.name, 'is eating')
  }
})

Object.assign(
  createEmployee.prototype, 
  eater()
)
 

function createEmployee(name, age){
    
  let Employee = Object.create(createEmployee.prototype)
   
  this.name = name 
  this.age = age 
   
  return Object.assign(Employee, this)
}

createEmployee.prototype.work = function(){
  console.log(this.name, 'is working')
} 

let emp = createEmployee('Muzaffer', 24)
console.log(emp.name)
emp.work()
emp.eat()
let emp2 = createEmployee('Cuma', 22)
console.log('after creating emp2')
emp.work()
emp.eat()
console.log(emp.name)
```

With `new` keyword

```js
const eater = () => ({
  eat(){
    console.log(this.name, 'is eating')
  }
})

Object.assign(
  createEmployee.prototype, 
  eater()
)
 

function createEmployee(name, age){
  
  this.name = name 
  this.age = age 
  
}
createEmployee.prototype.work = function(){
  console.log(this.name, 'is working')
} 

let emp = new createEmployee('Muzaffer', 24)
console.log(emp.name)
emp.work()
emp.eat()
let emp2 = new createEmployee('Cuma', 22)
console.log('after creating emp2')
emp.work()
emp.eat()
console.log(emp.name)
```

According to these result: `new` keyword just makes the prototype of the `this` object refer to `createEmployee.prototype`, like the `Object.create` call did before. And return `this` object. When calling a function with `new` keyword or just calling regular function `this` object create autumaticly.

But we dont need to use `this` keyword in `createEmployee` factory function. We just need `this` keyword in our object function like `work` and `eat`.

```js
const eater = () => ({
  eat(){
    console.log(this.name, 'is eating')
  }
})

Object.assign(
  createEmployee.prototype, 
  eater()
)
 

function createEmployee(name, age){
    
  let Employee = Object.create(createEmployee.prototype)
   
  Employee.name = name 
  Employee.age = age 
   
  return Employee 
}

createEmployee.prototype.work = function(){
  console.log(this.name, 'is working')
} 

let emp = createEmployee('Muzaffer', 24)
console.log(emp.name)
emp.work()
emp.eat()
let emp2 = createEmployee('Cuma', 22)
console.log('after creating emp2')
emp.work()
emp.eat()
console.log(emp.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works when using `this` keyword

```
const eater = () => ({
  eat(){
    console.log(this.name, 'is eating')
  }
})

Object.assign(
  createEmployee.prototype, 
  eater()
)
 

function createEmployee(name, age){
    
  let Employee = Object.create(createEmployee.prototype)
   
  this.name = name 
  this.age = age 
   
  return Object.assign(Employee, this)
}

createEmployee.prototype.work = function(){
  console.log(this.name, 'is working')
} 

let emp = createEmployee('Muzaffer', 24)
console.log(emp.name)
emp.work()
emp.eat()
let emp2 = createEmployee('Cuma', 22)
console.log('after creating emp2')
emp.work()
emp.eat()
console.log(emp.name)


/*
  
  //Output
 
Muzaffer
Muzaffer is working
Muzaffer is eating
after creating emp2
Muzaffer is working
Muzaffer is eating
Muzaffer
  
  
  
*/
```

Comment: If `createEmployee` uses `this`, it must be called with `new`. If you want to use `Object.create`, you should use `Employee.name = name` or `Object.assign(Employee, {name})`.

Comment: That `eater()` thing is still messed up, no reason to have a function that creates the method. You should define the `eat` method in exactly the same way as the `work` method.

Comment: I tried to make implementation composition via ```eater``` factory function. I know it can be defined like ```work```  function. We can use ```this``` keyword without calling constructor via ```new```. So why should I use ```new```.

Comment: I don't see where `eater` uses composition. And no, you cannot use `this` inside a factory function - make sure to enable strict mode and see it fail.

Comment: I merged ```eater``` with ```createEmployee.prototype``` this is composition. I dont need to use ```this``` in factory function anymore. Check my answer.